# my "video view" is blank when pressing the back button. How i can fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

So, i have a video view for my background. There i put image view as button. when i go to other activity and then go back, my video cannot play. just blank. Sorry about my english.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pilih_user);

        VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.start();

        ImageView apin = findViewById(R.id.pilihguru);

        apin.setOnClickListener(view ->

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PilihUser.this, DaftarPembelajaran.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

}
```

And this my layout. I use constraint and then put video view as background. This my first time to build simple app by java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutpilihuser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bghome"
    tools:context=".PilihUser">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pilihanak"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/videoView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pilihuser1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pilihguru"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pilihanak"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pilihuser2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Klox's response is correct: you need to override `onResume()` and restart your video. 
 To understand "why", please read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.  Please let us know if this worked; please feel free to "upvote" and/or "accept" Klox's  answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call videoview.start() in onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    videoview.start();

}
```